# Align icons to the middle inside circle

Tags: svg

Can you help me align the icon into the middle of the circle?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#545454"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.5 4a8.5 8.5 0 1 0 0 17 8.5 8.5 0 0 0 0-17zM2 12.5a9.5 9.5 0 1 1 19 0 9.5 9.5 0 0 1-19 0zm9 2v-7h1v7h-1zm0 3V16h1v1.5h-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFF"/>
    </g>
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#545454"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.92 2.514A1 1 0 0 1 8.794 2h1.412a1 1 0 0 1 .874.514l7.209 12.977a1 1 0 0 1-.042 1.04l-.683 1.024a1 1 0 0 1-.832.445H2.267a1 1 0 0 1-.832-.445L.753 16.53a1 1 0 0 1-.042-1.04l.437.242-.437-.242L7.92 2.514zM10.206 3H8.794L1.585 15.976 2.267 17h14.465l.683-1.024L10.205 3zM9 12.5V7h1v5.5H9zM9 15v-1.25h1V15H9z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFF"/>
    </g>
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="31" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g>
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#545454"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.5 4a6.5 6.5 0 1 0 0 13 6.5 6.5 0 0 0 0-13zM2 10.5a7.5 7.5 0 1 1 15 0 7.5 7.5 0 0 1-15 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFF"/><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 14.75V13.5h1v1.25H9zM9.5 7A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 8 8.5H7a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 3.118 2.423.221.221 0 0 0-.104.058.07.07 0 0 0-.014.02v1.249H9V11c0-.574.457-.94.872-1.046A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 7z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFF"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: a possible solition to your problem would be translating the paths inside the icon. For example for the first icon you may need to translate the path `transform="translate(.5,-.5)"` In order to know how much to translate you need the bounding box of the path and the center of the icon. _However_ this is a BAD solution. The real solution here is to redraw your paths or use icons already drawn by others.

Comment: Please include relevant code inline in your question - codepen links are not sufficient because external links tend to rot.